# What is a Tensor Product?

Tags: group-theory, definition, tensor-products

If you were to explain the concept of a tensor product to an undergraduate(post linear algebra), how would you do so?

I would like to hear your definition, your take, on the definition of a tensor product. Explain what exact it means to tensor modules over a ring. And, if you feel it necessary, explain the significance of multiple tensor products, $\bigotimes$.

Comment: I would just not explain what a tensor product is to anyone who does not know linear algebra. I am sorry, but this is not a sensible question... Have you looked in the site for questions related to this? I am sure people have asked this already.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Edited

Comment: [The Tensor Product, Demystified](https://www.math3ma.com/blog/the-tensor-product-demystified) is the clearest explanation I've read to-date. And I've read at least a dozen other explanations (including the answers here) and took a class that covered them, without feeling like I gained a meaningful understanding of them. Hope this helps someone else like it helped me!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In linear algebra, we deal with vector spaces and linear maps, and we are happy.
But we also want to talk about inner products, bilinear forms and such things, and these are *not* linear maps. Instead of developing a completelu new theory, we do what we do best: reduce the problem to one we know how to solve. The tensor product allows us to turn *bilinear* maps $V\times W\to U$ into *linear* maps $V\otimes W\to U$. And this makes us happy again. This is important, because we like being happy.

Once we have established that, I would explain the actual construction and basic properties of the tensor product to an undergraduate by pointing him to the library. People with a reasonable background of linear algebra are perfectly prepared, in my experience, to read the construction and so on.

Comment: I *love* being happy!

Comment: Being happy makes me happy!

Comment: i hate being happy

Answer (score 7):

https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~wtg10/tensors3.html

Timothy Gowers posted this on his website. He has a very good explanation of tensor product, it's definition, and why we use it. I found it very useful when I was beginning my study of them.

Comment: It's a pity that page in that link isn't LaTeXed: as it is I find it almost painful to try to read it.

Comment: yeah true. But very insightful.

Comment: Perhaps...I can't tell: I just couldn't read it.